# How to update a map but only when key already exists

Tags: elixir

I have been writing a lot of elixir and one thing that keeps cropping my code is when I want to update the value of a map only if the key already exists, I end up with code like this:

```
def incSomething(state, key) do
  {_, state} = get_and_update_in(state.way.down.there[key], fn
    nil -> :pop
    j -> {nil, j + 1}
  end)
state
end
```

Sometimes there's a lot of code involved and sometimes there are nested get_and_update_ins so it gets messy.

I initially found myself wanting to use the `update_in/2` macro, but it seems to function as more of an upsert than an update rather like the difference between `update` and `replace into` in sql.

`Map.update/4` allows you to set a default, but doesn't allow you to not set anything.  `Map.update!/3` outright errors if the key is missing.

Is there a less awkward way to do this in the standard language?  Or do I have to write my own?

Comment: The closest thing I found was `Map.replace/3` but it accepts a key and a value; you can't pass a function which takes the old value and returns a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up actually using.  Because my data types were deeply nested I prefer to use a macro in the style of `update_in/2`.

```
defmodule ReplaceIn do

  defmacro replace_in(path, fun) do
    quote do
      get_and_update_in(unquote(path), fn
        nil -> :pop
        x -> {nil, unquote(fun).(x)}
      end) |> elem(1)
    end
  end

  def replace_in(data, keys, fun) do
    get_and_update_in(data, keys, fn
      nil -> :pop
      x -> {nil, fun.(x)}
    end) |> elem(1)
  end
end
```

And it can be used exactly the same as `update_in/2`.

```
> require ReplaceIn
> a = %{b: %{c: 1}}
> ReplaceIn.replace_in(a.b[:c], fn x -> x + 1 end)
%{b: %{c: 2}}
> ReplaceIn.replace_in(a.b[:d], fn x -> x + 1 end)
%{b: %{c: 1}}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Map.replace/3` to do exactly that - update the value of a key, only if that key exists in the map.

This function is available only since Elixir 1.5, for previous versions you'll need to implement it yourself. Fortunately, it's rather easy.

```
def update_existing(map, key, value) do
  case map do
    %{^key => _} -> %{map | key => value}
    %{} -> map
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the function-style update you could modify it slightly:

```
def update_existing(map, key, fun) do
  case map do
    %{^key => old} -> %{map | key => fun.(old)}
    %{} -> map
  end
end
```

Comment: Like that code--best sort of FP.  Simple and clean.

Comment: I don't like to quibble, but strictly speaking I would need a macro in the style of `get_and_update_in` in order to truly solve this.  The source for the `update_in` macro seems rather complicated to me, but I'm sure it could be done.